# MySQL Function Update row every minute

Tags: mysql

I want to update all my rows like this:

[image]

For every row:
new amount = current amount + speed

My first idea was to use PHP, but mysql functions are much easier and better in performance, I guess.

Comment: `update table set amount=amount+speed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple single update should suffice.

```
update your_table
set amount = amount + speed;
```

However, it is usually a dangerous idea to update without a `where` clause. Make sure that this is what you want or apply the suitable `where` clause.

Comment: I dont need where because I'm updating all rows